# Is this a good idea to use Yii Framework with Doctrine 2 ORM?

Tags: php, symfony, yii, doctrine-orm, domain-model

I love Yii Framework, it works fast, it's pretty cool and easy to develop with.
But now I have a problem - I am going to develop Learning Managment System with difficult domain logic and it's not good for me to use Active Record from Yii for my models, it would be better to separate mapping and domain logic.

So I decided to use Doctrine 2 ORM. It's pretty cool too, I liked it when previously I worked with it. But I think it's enough big for not so big Yii Framework.

the main problems are

1) I need some kind of ORM for separate domain logic and mapping. Are there any alternatives for Doctrine 2 ORM?

2) I need good framework to work with this ORM. Is Yii well-suited to use it with Doctrine 2 ORM? Will it lose its benefits when I will use such big and not so fast ORM as Doctrine 2? Maybe it would be better to use Symfony 2 framework to work with Doctrine 2 ORM because they are natively in couple

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but we like concrete questions with reproducible problems. Your analysis is too shallow: "pretty cool" etc. I don't think, it's possible to give you a correct answer, based upon such vague data. You'll have to make a decision yourself.

Comment: @user4035 the main problems are

Comment: @user4035 

1) I need fast and functional ORM to use it with some php framework

2) I need fast and functional framework to work with this ORM

3) Is Yii + Doctrine 2 a good couple and saves its benefits?

Answer (score 2):

RedBeanPHP is an easy to use open source object relational mapping (ORM) software for Yii framework. Created by Gabor de Mooij in the Netherlands, it is licensed under GPL and New BSD.

RedBeanPHP is used as the database abstraction layer for your Application.

Learn more about RedBeanPHP here: http://www.redbeanphp.com

Comment: The simple fact that it uses statics and directly using properties already a no-go for me.

Comment: I am agree with @Anyone - using static methods is not good idea for ORM because it can cause problems for unit testing but all the same - thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have complicated domain model (not just CRUD) Doctrine2 is fine and it is framework ignostic so you can use it with yii2 and use Yii2 just for the delivery mechanism (Web,Console or others) just note that you have to make data providers like those pre-existed in yii (Maybe RepositoryDataProvider or QueryObjectDataProvider), but I think using a big ORM for reading data especialy for reporting (Grids, lists charts etc) is not a good idea so I can use doctrine for writing (when the domain logic is applied) and Yii2 Dbal for reading because the Yii2 db infrastructure is realy fast